# What should I store for identify an Interval in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have a problem with setInterval and clearInterval in NodeJS. I want to create a monitoring service for websites. I'm planning to implement a web service that gets the URL and value of monitoring interval and call setInterval() method. Everything is ok so far.

After that, I want to save the URL,interval and an identifier for setInterval object to DB for future operation. But only identifier for setInterval method is an object. I can not store this object in an array on the server side because when I restarted the project, all the objects disappear.

Does anyone have any proper solution for this case ? You can see my example code below.

```
var timeout = (parseInt(req.body.timeout) * (60 * 1000));
var query = {
    website: req.body.website,
    timeout: timeout
}
var id = setInterval(checker(query), timeout); // This returns an object so it can not be stored in DB.
query.id = id;
console.log(id);
store.save('websites', query).then(function(query) {
    res.send({
        code: 200,
        message: 'SUCCESS',
        data: query
    });
}).fail(function(err) {
    res.send({
        code: 500,
        message: 'FAIL_SYSTEM',
        data: err
    });
})
```

Comment: Database is meant for persistent data. If the information you want to store is not persistent (i.e. it "disappears" after a server restart) then the DB is not the right place to store it. You could store it as a global variable, as global variables die when the server gets shut down.

Comment: yeah, I can solve this situation with an init function that takes all the rows from DB and call setInterval method for each when every time server restarts. But I'm afraid for overload of memory if I store every Interval object as a global variable.

Comment: totally legitimate question, don't really understand the downvote

Answer (score 1):

If you want persistent recurring tasks, you should use something else than setInterval.

Check out libraries like [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda)